# Track Email Code snippet included in email, yet no opens are being recorded

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sql

I'm using the data view to query opens for the last 30 days. It's been working for the past 2 months.

My devs just re-wrote our HTML based email with it's ampscript but the code is still there. I performed the same test as always, changing the EmailID, then sending myself the email, but this time no opens are being picked up by the query.

Any clue? This is quite urgent - my go live is Tuesday and this was working all the time before!!!!

Comment: Did you check if the Track Email Opens snippet was added to the HTML ?

Comment: @ZakBen yes, as I mentioned, it is.

Comment: Are you doing a test send? Regular send? Did you check the overview of sent emails in Email Studio to verify the send in UI?

Comment: Is the track email wrapped in any conditional ampscript? Is there any conditions in your query that could exclude your test? If you can provide the query and relevant code in email, would help us with debugging

Comment: The emails are being sent out of Journey Builder. The job information under Tracking > Journey Builder Sends show that the emails have all been opened. However, the data view which was working before, no longer is. It won't populate the data extension. This is the query (which was working up until this Thursday):

Comment: Select 
j.JobID,
j.EmailName,
o.EventDate as OpenTime,
s.EmailAddress,
s.SubscriberKey,
j.EmailID,
a.CountryFromIP

from [_Job] j
join [_Open] o
on j.JobID = o.JobID
join [_Subscribers] s
on o.SubscriberID = s.SubscriberID
join slotsia_master a
on s.SubscriberKey = a.SubscriberKey

where
o.IsUnique = 1 and
o.EventDate > dateadd(d,-30,getdate()) and
j.EmailID = 5610

Yes, I've changed the EmailID to reflect the new template (we've done this 7 times so far). But even the "last modified date" of the data extension isn't showing that the automation is linked to it.

Answer (score 0):

The Data Views can at times have a delay in being populated. In my experience the Open view is the most likely to have delays. A recent release from Salesforce has added a new feature to reduce the amount of "false positives" in email opens and clicks that are the result of ISPs or MTAs opening and clicking emails (for SPAM and Phishing Detection, which has long plagued Marketing Cloud's reporting for large enterprise customers [in my experience]).

Double-check that the open tag in Marketing Cloud is correct. Previously I have seen people erroneously take their open tracking pixel from an email they received and insert it into their email template, which would record all opens against their own record. I mention this as your developers have recently re-coded the email. Re-insert it via the UI to be double-sure.

Be confident that the open tag is featured in the email and that some code isn't preventing it from being delivered. Best would be that you exist as a seed in your live send, otherwise send a test to yourself under the same conditions the live send was performed. View the source code of the email you have received (check your software manual) and find the open tag.

If the above doesn't reveal a problem after you've accounted for some possible delay, contact Salesforce Support.